# Another unexpected result from Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, gdi+

In the following code:

```
void f10(Graphics g)
{
    var img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    img.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
    var destRect = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
    destRect.Inflate(-5, -5);
    g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), destRect);
    var srcRect = new RectangleF(-.5f, -.5f, img.Width, img.Height);
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawImage(img, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    f10(e.Graphics);
}

private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width + "x" + pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

I get the following result:

[Result http://www.uploadup.com/di-XJ2I.png](http://www.uploadup.com/di-XJ2I.png)

The form contains a picture box that fits the whole inside content of the form and a text box that shows the dimensions of the picture box. I expect the right side of the black box to fit the whole inside of the blue rectangle. Why it doesn't?!

[gap http://www.uploadup.com/di-YGWL.png](http://www.uploadup.com/di-YGWL.png)

By changing the values of dimensions (resizing the picture box) the gap changes.

---

i used the following code to find offset of the bug based on the image width value:

```
void f11(Graphics g)
{
    var img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    img.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
    var bmp = new Bitmap(10010, 6);
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 3, bmp.Height);
    var bmpG = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    var srcRect = new RectangleF(-.5f, -.5f, img.Width, img.Height);
    bmpG.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
    g.DrawString("Please Wait...", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
    for (; destRect.Width < bmp.Width; destRect.Width++)
    {
        bmpG.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Blue), new Rectangle(destRect.X, destRect.Y, destRect.Width-1, destRect.Height-1));
        bmpG.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(destRect.X+1, destRect.Y+1, destRect.Width-2, destRect.Height-2), srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        //g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(bmp.GetPixel(destRect.Width-2, 1)), pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
        int n = 0;
        while (!bmp.GetPixel(destRect.Width - 2 - n, 1).ToArgb().Equals(Color.Black.ToArgb())) n++;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", destRect.Width-2, n);
    }
    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(pictureBox1.BackColor), pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    g.DrawString("Done.", SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    f11(e.Graphics);
}
```

the result is:

[Result](http://hamidi2.persiangig.com/result.txt)

can you help me find a way to workaround it?
thanks

Comment: What does `910126` mean?

Comment: GDI+ has off-by-one bugs.  You'll need to start using FillRectangle and TextureBrush.

Comment: would you please describe more? indeed i'm not going to draw a black box. finally, the image will not be just a simple pixel. what i said was the reduced problem. is there any workaround for the bug? does MS knows about it? is there any hotfix?

Comment: coder: what do u mean by dispose?
Sascha: it's a tag indicating when i have posted the message. for example, today is 26th day of the first month of year 1391 in the Jalali calendar we use. since i'm not familiar with Gregorian calendar and want to know when i posted the question, i use the tag. it also helps me find my own questions between a couple of posts. it's kinda my sign ;)

Comment: i appended a new result to the post. please scroll up.